# How to do or perform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Ho would you do the below
Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to perform stress test on AWS architecture some of them are Jmeter, Blazemeter etc. Regarding restriction you have to let AWS support know before hand regarding the stress test or penetration test you are going to perform on the AWS infrastructure you have created. Check this link for more details.

https://aws.amazon.com/security/penetration-testing/

Answer (score 0):

Since you pay for bytes into and out of the Amazon infrastructure, to maintain low costs keep your load generators in the same data center as your application under test. There are some drawbacks to this, but the primary one is that your network will lack the complexity of impairment that real users will experience.  If you are using a tool which includes modeling of network impairment with the virtual users then this drawback is reduced.

No matter what tool you use, if you have the load generators running on virtual machines in AWS, you will face the issue of clock float on the virtual machine clock.  Periodically this virtual clock will need to be resync'd to the system clock on the hypervisor host.  This will result in clock jump.  This will happen while you have a timing record open - it is unavoidable.   The net impact of this is that you will have higher average, percentile values, standard deviation and maximums than if you were running on physical hardware.